# file_get_contents with get variable

Tags: php

I have a site that is in php and generates a report

Im trying to convert to a PDF

My code:

```
<?php
file_get_contents("http://domain.com/report.php?clid=Company Name");
?>
```

I get a Blank Page

If i go to:

```
http://domain.com/report.php?clid=Company Name
```

Page renders fine

If i run:

```
php testhtml.php
```

I get no errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) of `file_get_contents`:

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you
>   need to encode the URI with `urlencode`.

Also, remember to `echo` it:

```
echo file_get_contents(
    "http://domain.com/report.php?clid=". urlencode("Company Name")
);
```